# Deploying Ember.js app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ember.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have tried and search how I and deploy emberjs app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk but I can not find a way.
I am using EB CLI for deployment and configuration.

If anyone has an experience in deployment of ember app to Elastic Beanstalk please share.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit why you want to use Elastic Beanstalk? Are you using [Ember Fastboot](https://ember-fastboot.com/)? Otherwise an Ember deployment is just a bunch of static files hosted somewhere. The common deployment on AWS for that scenario uses S3 and CloudFront. Ember-cli-deploy covers it [in its documentation](http://ember-cli-deploy.com/docs/v1.0.x/s3-walkthrough/).

Comment: Hi @jelhan, 
You are right. I am new in ember and AWS so don't know the working environment.
No, I am not using Ember Fastboot.

Comment: In that case I would recommend to use S3 and CloudFront instead. Will safe you complexity and money. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As @jelhan mention in a thread comment section, you should not need ElasticBeanstalk to host static files. If you're not using ember-fastboot, then just use S3 and CloudFront.

You can also use AWS amplify https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/console/

That aside, to get your app on Elastic Beanstalk, use the following steps:

1. Update/add a dist path to `"dist/www"` inside `.ember-cli.js` file:

```
      "outputPath": "dist/www"
```

2. Add a `package.json`

```
   {
      "name": "ember_frontend_server",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "We are using node server to serve static files",
      "main": "server.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "path": "^0.12.7"
      }
    }
```

3. Add a `server.js` file to host static files

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path')

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || process.argv[2] || 8081;

app.use(express.static(path.normalize(__dirname + '/www')))

app.use('*', (req, res) =>
{
  res.sendFile(__dirname +'/www/index.html');
});

app.listen(port);
```

4. Initialize elastic beanstalk setup by eb init
5. deploy the app to elastic beanstalk by running eb deploy command